# Save multiple questions as drafts

Tags: feature-request

There are multiple times I have certain questions but I don't have the time to write their body and format them properly at that point of time. I have to then use an external To-Do List app to remember my questions. Is there a way currently to save multiple question as drafts on the site itself?

[image: User Navbar]

It would be great if AskUbuntu had a specific section called 'drafts' for it in the user profile page where it maintains lists of all my answers, questions, tags, badges etc.

Comment: There isn't such section. But you can save a draft for one question at a time which will be the for 7 days. Draft can be retrieved when you click on Ask Question button.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes I am aware of that feature, but I wish they could extend it to multiple questions instead of one question at a time, similar to how Gmail maintains drafts.

Comment: This probably needs to be asked at https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [Expand draft feature to allow multiple drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141834), [List all my drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73148)